# Where to find old ffmpeg/ffprobe documentation?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

There are several different versions of `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` flying around, and each version has a different API.

If I `apt-get install ffmpeg` on Ubuntu 16.04, I get ffmpeg `version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`. If I install `apt-get install ffmpeg` on Ubuntu 18.04, I get `version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

When I visit the [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html), it says "The following documentation is regenerated nightly, and corresponds to the newest FFmpeg revision. Consult your locally installed documentation for older versions." That is, the hosted documentation is neither of those two versions.

So I have two questions:

- What does it mean "your locally installed documentation"? Is it only talking about `man ffmpeg`? Or is there some way to host the documentation as a webpage?
- Are there any places that simply host the older versions of the ffmpeg documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean "your locally installed documentation"? Is it only talking about `man ffmpeg`?

It is referring to the various man pages and `ffmpeg -h`.

> Are there any places that simply host the older versions of the ffmpeg documentation?

You can make it yourself. Install the *build-essential* and *texinfo* packages, [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) the source code for your FFmpeg version, then make the HTML documentation:

```
./configure
make doc
```

The HTML files will be located in the `doc` directory.

Alternatively, and more recommended, [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) a recent version from the git master branch and use the online documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who uses docker and wants to just host the docs without thinking too much, this is the Dockerfile I came up with.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install requirements for ffmpeg doc generation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git build-essential texinfo yasm
# Install requirements for minimal webserver
RUN apt-get install -y webfs mime-support && update-mime

RUN git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git

# Checkout the version that you want
RUN cd ffmpeg \
  && git checkout tags/n2.8.15 \
  && ./configure \
  && make doc

WORKDIR /ffmpeg/doc

CMD webfsd -F -p 80
```

Then you can

```
docker build -t ffmpeg-doc .
docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 ffmpeg-doc
```

And visit `http://localhost` for the list of generated files. The common ones will be `http://localhost/ffmpeg.html` or `http://localhost/ffprobe.html`.